# How to access a right item button on navigation bar in XCUITest?

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I am writing UITest cases for my iOS Swift app. In the app I have created a custom right item button on the navigation bar in this way:

```
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

Now I don't know how to access this custom right item button in XCUITest and really need some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot access a `UIBarButtonItem`, because it is not a real UIElement (it is not a `UIView` subclass), but you probably want to access the `UIButton` inside your right bar button item anyway.

There are several ways how you could access the button, here are two ideas:

**1. Query the first button in the navigation bar**

```
let rightNavBarButton = XCUIApplication().navigationBars.children(matching: .button).firstMatch
XCTAssert(rightNavBarButton.exists)
```

That way you access the first `UIButton` inside a `UINavigationBar`.

This only works if there is only one button in your navigation bar. So it will break when you add another button.

**2. Use an accessibility identifier**

You can define a accessibility identifier for the button inside your right bar button item and use that to access it during the test:

In your app:

```
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
barButtonItem.accessibilityIdentifier = "navbarRightItem"
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

In your test:

```
let rightNavBarButton = XCUIApplication().navigationBars.buttons["navbarRightItem"]
XCTAssert(rightNavBarButton.exists)
```

Just make sure you are using `accessibilityIdentifier` and not `accessibilityLabel`. Because `accessibilityLabel` will be read by VoiceOver for handicapped users and should contain useful text.

Comment: It still doesn't work. XCTAssert(rightNavBarButton.exists) failed. But anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your customView a UIButton?

Comment: Actually the customView was a UIView, which contains an UIImageView to host an image. I changed the customView to a UIButton and then it worked by app.navigationBars["myNavigationBarAccessibilityIdentifier"].buttons.element(boundBy: 0).tap(). Thanks!

Comment: The reason I was not using UIButton for the rightBarButtonItem's customView is that UIButton's setImage method doesn't work well with a custom image. But that is another topic though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign an `accessibilityIdentifier` to the button

```
barButtonItem.accessibilityIdentifier = “barButtonItemID”
```

If didn’t work set `IsAccessibilityElement` to YES/true